# Multiple Hodge integrals and integrability

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, integrable-systems, enumerative-geometry, string-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

It is known that a generating function of the linear Hodge integrals is a tau function of the KP hierarchy, namely a one-parameter deformation of the Kontsevich-Witten tau-function  (see [Kazarian](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.3263)). Are there known any generating functions of the multiple Hodge integrals (integrals with multiple $\lambda$-classes) with nice integrable properties?

Answer (score 6):

There's been a lot of interest on *triple* Hodge integrals in the last 10 years, mostly after the work of Mariño and Vafa on framed knots (see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0108064)). The question of integrability was first studied, as far as I am aware, by Jian Zhou in his paper on [Hodge Integrals and Integrable Hierarchies](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310408), where two subcases (1-partition and 2-partition triple Hodge integrals) are found to be related to KP and 2-Toda respectively. The general case is considered by Aganagic, Dijkgraaf, Klemm, Mariño and Vafa in their [Topological Strings and Integrable Hierarchies](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0312085) paper; the relevant integrable hierarchy is the 3-KP hierarchy. See also Mariño's book on Chern-Simons, Matrix models and Topstrings about it.

Slightly switching to autobiography, a somewhat different interpretation of the multi-Hodge integrals generating functions as dispersive deformations of the Witten-Kontsevich tau funcion is alluded to [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0281). This is closer in spirit to the Dubrovin-Zhang study of 1+1 integrable hierarchies of topological type.